# How to transpose a nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this

```
[('a1','b1','c1'),('a2','b2','c2'),('a3','b3','c3'),('a4','b4','c4')]
```

And i want to get the record from the above list like this,

```
['a1','a2','a3','a4']
['b1','b2','b3','b4']
['c1','c2','c3','c4']
```

I am new to python, so please any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: Where is `'a b c...4'`?

Comment: i have updated.@jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: `[list(i) for i in zip(*l)]`?

Comment: any suggestion how to do ? please

Comment: You need `zip`. `a = [('a1','b1','c1'),('a2','b2','c2'),('a3','b3','c3'),('a4','b4','c4')]; print(list(zip(*a)))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take also note of [How much research effort is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098).

Comment: Hi @jizhihaoSAMA  ,can you please help me by doing this ? I have a list=['a, b, c, d', 'e, f, g, h','i, j, k, l'] and i want to get a list like this changed_list =[ ['a','b','c','d'] ['e','f','g','h'] ['i','j','k','l'] ] , how can i achieve please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as transposing, and you can do it like this:

```
lst = [('a1','b1','c1'),('a2','b2','c2'),('a3','b3','c3'),('a4','b4','c4')]
transposed_lst = list(zip(*lst))
```

`transposed_lst` evaluates to:

```
[('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'), ('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4')]
```

Comment: You should also `*transposed_lst` in the end because the expected answer is not a list of tuples

Comment: Hi @Hedy can you please help me by doing this ? I have a list=['a, b, c, d', 'e, f, g, h','i, j, k, l'] and i want to get a list like this changed_list =[ ['a','b','c','d'] ['e','f','g','h'] ['i','j','k','l'] ]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a list comprehension

```
list = [('a1','b1','c1'),('a2','b2','c2'),('a3','b3','c3'), ('a4 ', 'b4', 'c4']

a = [x[0] for x in list]
b = [x[1] for x in list]
c = [x[2] for x in list]
```

If you print `a,b,c` you will get this output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Comment: Hi @hedy, can you please help me by doing this ?  I have a list=['a, b, c, d', 'e, f, g, h','i, j, k, l']   and i want to get a list like this changed_list =[
 ['a','b','c','d']
 ['e','f','g','h']
 ['i','j','k','l']
]

Comment: Please help me  as it help me for learning things. Thanks